# how to pause and resume a surfaceView

Tags: java, android

Why when minimizing an application does it not expand back? At the start screen, it is possible to make a purchase through BillingManager. If you do not start the purchase and minimize the application, then deployment back occurs, but if the purchase screen starts and minimize the application, then it cannot be expanded back. I get an error in the logs
`2023-10-29 16:33:43.324 8592-25240/com.controlledbattles.bigbattlesimulator.app E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`

```
public class SDLSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    View.OnKeyListener, View.OnTouchListener, SensorEventListener  {

    // Sensors
    protected SensorManager mSensorManager;
    protected Display mDisplay;

    // Keep track of the surface size to normalize touch events
    protected float mWidth, mHeight;

    // Is SurfaceView ready for rendering
    public boolean mIsSurfaceReady;

    // Startup
    public SDLSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        setOnKeyListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        mDisplay = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        setOnGenericMotionListener(SDLActivity.getMotionListener());

        // Some arbitrary defaults to avoid a potential division by zero
        mWidth = 1.0f;
        mHeight = 1.0f;

        mIsSurfaceReady = false;
    }

    public void handlePause() {
        enableSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, false);
    }

    public void handleResume() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        setOnKeyListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        enableSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, true);
    }

    public Surface getNativeSurface() {
        return getHolder().getSurface();
    }

    // Called when we have a valid drawing surface
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.v("SDL", "surfaceCreated()");
        SDLActivity.onNativeSurfaceCreated();
    }



    // Called when the surface is resized
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.v("SDL", "surfaceChanged()");

        if (SDLActivity.mSingleton == null) {
            return;
        }

        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        int nDeviceWidth = width;
        int nDeviceHeight = height;
        try
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17 /* Android 4.2 (JELLY_BEAN_MR1) */) {
                DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                mDisplay.getRealMetrics( realMetrics );
                nDeviceWidth = realMetrics.widthPixels;
                nDeviceHeight = realMetrics.heightPixels;
            }
        } catch(Exception ignored) {
        }

        synchronized(SDLActivity.getContext()) {
            // In case we're waiting on a size change after going fullscreen, send a notification.
            SDLActivity.getContext().notifyAll();
        }

        Log.v("SDL", "Window size: " + width + "x" + height);
        Log.v("SDL", "Device size: " + nDeviceWidth + "x" + nDeviceHeight);
        SDLActivity.nativeSetScreenResolution(width, height, nDeviceWidth, nDeviceHeight, mDisplay.getRefreshRate());
        SDLActivity.onNativeResize();

        // Prevent a screen distortion glitch,
        // for instance when the device is in Landscape and a Portrait App is resumed.
        boolean skip = false;
        int requestedOrientation = SDLActivity.mSingleton.getRequestedOrientation();

        if (requestedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || requestedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT) {
            if (mWidth > mHeight) {
               skip = true;
            }
        } else if (requestedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || requestedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE) {
            if (mWidth < mHeight) {
               skip = true;
            }
        }

        // Special Patch for Square Resolution: Black Berry Passport
        if (skip) {
           double min = Math.min(mWidth, mHeight);
           double max = Math.max(mWidth, mHeight);

           if (max / min < 1.20) {
              Log.v("SDL", "Don't skip on such aspect-ratio. Could be a square resolution.");
              skip = false;
           }
        }

        // Don't skip in MultiWindow.
        if (skip) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 /* Android 7.0 (N) */) {
                if (SDLActivity.mSingleton.isInMultiWindowMode()) {
                    Log.v("SDL", "Don't skip in Multi-Window");
                    skip = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (skip) {
           Log.v("SDL", "Skip .. Surface is not ready.");
           mIsSurfaceReady = false;
           return;
        }

        /* If the surface has been previously destroyed by onNativeSurfaceDestroyed, recreate it here */
        SDLActivity.onNativeSurfaceChanged();

        /* Surface is ready */
        mIsSurfaceReady = true;

        SDLActivity.mNextNativeState = SDLActivity.NativeState.RESUMED;
        SDLActivity.handleNativeState();
    }

    // Called when we lose the surface
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {

            Log.v("SDL", "surfaceDestroyed()");

            // Transition to pause, if needed
            SDLActivity.mNextNativeState = SDLActivity.NativeState.PAUSED;
            SDLActivity.handleNativeState();

            mIsSurfaceReady = false;
            SDLActivity.onNativeSurfaceDestroyed();

    }

    // Key events
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return SDLActivity.handleKeyEvent(v, keyCode, event, null);
    }

    // Touch events
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        /* Ref: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html */
        int touchDevId = event.getDeviceId();
        final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int pointerFingerId;
        int i = -1;
        float x,y,p;

        /*
         * Prevent id to be -1, since it's used in SDL internal for synthetic events
         * Appears when using Android emulator, eg:
         *  adb shell input mouse tap 100 100
         *  adb shell input touchscreen tap 100 100
         */
        if (touchDevId < 0) {
            touchDevId -= 1;
        }

        // 12290 = Samsung DeX mode desktop mouse
        // 12290 = 0x3002 = 0x2002 | 0x1002 = SOURCE_MOUSE | SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        // 0x2   = SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER
        if (event.getSource() == InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE || event.getSource() == (InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE | InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN)) {
            int mouseButton = 1;
            try {
                Object object = event.getClass().getMethod("getButtonState").invoke(event);
                if (object != null) {
                    mouseButton = (Integer) object;
                }
            } catch(Exception ignored) {
            }

            // We need to check if we're in relative mouse mode and get the axis offset rather than the x/y values
            // if we are.  We'll leverage our existing mouse motion listener
            SDLGenericMotionListener_API12 motionListener = SDLActivity.getMotionListener();
            x = motionListener.getEventX(event);
            y = motionListener.getEventY(event);

            SDLActivity.onNativeMouse(mouseButton, action, x, y, motionListener.inRelativeMode());
        } else {
            switch(action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    for (i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                        pointerFingerId = event.getPointerId(i);
                        x = event.getX(i) / mWidth;
                        y = event.getY(i) / mHeight;
                        p = event.getPressure(i);
                        if (p > 1.0f) {
                            // may be larger than 1.0f on some devices
                            // see the documentation of getPressure(i)
                            p = 1.0f;
                        }
                        SDLActivity.onNativeTouch(touchDevId, pointerFingerId, action, x, y, p);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Primary pointer up/down, the index is always zero
                    i = 0;
                    /* fallthrough */
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    // Non primary pointer up/down
                    if (i == -1) {
                        i = event.getActionIndex();
                    }

                    pointerFingerId = event.getPointerId(i);
                    x = event.getX(i) / mWidth;
                    y = event.getY(i) / mHeight;
                    p = event.getPressure(i);
                    if (p > 1.0f) {
                        // may be larger than 1.0f on some devices
                        // see the documentation of getPressure(i)
                        p = 1.0f;
                    }
                    SDLActivity.onNativeTouch(touchDevId, pointerFingerId, action, x, y, p);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    for (i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                        pointerFingerId = event.getPointerId(i);
                        x = event.getX(i) / mWidth;
                        y = event.getY(i) / mHeight;
                        p = event.getPressure(i);
                        if (p > 1.0f) {
                            // may be larger than 1.0f on some devices
                            // see the documentation of getPressure(i)
                            p = 1.0f;
                        }
                        SDLActivity.onNativeTouch(touchDevId, pointerFingerId, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, p);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return true;
   }

    // Sensor events
    public void enableSensor(int sensortype, boolean enabled) {
        // TODO: This uses getDefaultSensor - what if we have >1 accels?
        if (enabled) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensortype),
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, null);
        } else {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
                            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensortype));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            // Since we may have an orientation set, we won't receive onConfigurationChanged events.
            // We thus should check here.
            int newOrientation;

            float x, y;
            switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    x = -event.values[1];
                    y = event.values[0];
                    newOrientation = SDLActivity.SDL_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    x = event.values[1];
                    y = -event.values[0];
                    newOrientation = SDLActivity.SDL_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    x = -event.values[0];
                    y = -event.values[1];
                    newOrientation = SDLActivity.SDL_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_FLIPPED;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                default:
                    x = event.values[0];
                    y = event.values[1];
                    newOrientation = SDLActivity.SDL_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                    break;
            }

            if (newOrientation != SDLActivity.mCurrentOrientation) {
                SDLActivity.mCurrentOrientation = newOrientation;
                SDLActivity.onNativeOrientationChanged(newOrientation);
            }

            SDLActivity.onNativeAccel(-x / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,
                                      y / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,
                                      event.values[2] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);


        }
    }

    // Captured pointer events for API 26.
    public boolean onCapturedPointerEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        float x, y;
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                x = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_HSCROLL, 0);
                y = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL, 0);
                SDLActivity.onNativeMouse(0, action, x, y, false);
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX(0);
                y = event.getY(0);
                SDLActivity.onNativeMouse(0, action, x, y, true);
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE:

                // Change our action value to what SDL's code expects.
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS) {
                    action = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                } else { /* MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE */
                    action = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                }

                x = event.getX(0);
                y = event.getY(0);
                int button = event.getButtonState();

                SDLActivity.onNativeMouse(button, action, x, y, true);
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```